# Select html input triggers after second click in chrome for android but in desktop web browsers works ok, the app is developed in react js

Tags: android, html, select, react-hooks, onclick

I am just posting a little example because the code is big

This is in the function

```
const[Municipios, setMunicipios] = useState("");

const cargarMunicipio = function(e){
 const opcion = e.target.value;
 setMunicipios(opcion);
 console.log("Municip", opcion)

}
```

//This is in render

```
<select name="categorias" id="setCategorias" onClick={cargarMunicipio} className="inputt3" 
required>

 { 
     idDepartamentos >= 0 &&(
        departamentos[idDepartamentos].ciudades.map((item,i)=>(
           <option key={i} value={item}> {item}</option>
           

         
         ))
      )
 }
</select>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the onClick, the correct event was onChange and then worked in desktop and android browsers.